# How to search for a list of file name on the server using linux bash shell tool

Tags: python, linux, search

I am looking to see if the server has file name that i m looking for. I have list of file names on the text file and want to see whether these files existed in the server. Is there a way that I can do that either in python or in linux bash shell tool

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files holds the names as one per line, the following should work:

```
find / -type f | grep -f **filenames**
```

Please allow for a lengthy period of time to complete, if your machine is
slow or has lots of files.

If locate (updatedb) is available/up-and-running the following may be quicker.

```
locate -r . | grep -f **filenames**
```